# angular-animate broke my Boilerplate App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, bower, boilerplate

im building an app with boilerplate on angularjs 1.4.9. Now i added angular-animate via 'bower install angular-animate' and since then, every 'grunt watch' ends in an error:

```
Firefox 43.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) AppCtrl isCurrentUrl should pass a dummy test FAILED
minErr/<@C:/path/to/app/src/main/webapp/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
```

My browser error stack looks like:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngBoilerplate due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngBoilerplate.briefings_create due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngAnimate due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngAnimate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/nomod?p0=ngAnimate
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:2006:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:1930:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:2004:14)
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4447:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:341:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4431:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4448:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:341:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4431:5)
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngAnimate&p1=Error%…80%2Fpath%2Fto%2F%2Fapp%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4431%3A5)
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4470:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:341:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4431:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4448:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:341:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4431:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4448:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:341:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4431:5)
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngBoilerplate.brief…80%2Fpath%2Fto%2F%2Fapp%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4431%3A5)
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4470:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:341:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4431:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4448:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:341:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4431:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:4356:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:1677:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:1698:12)
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngBoilerplate&p1=Er…0%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fapp%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1698%3A12)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:68(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4470forEach @ angular.js:341loadModules @ angular.js:4431createInjector @ angular.js:4356doBootstrap @ angular.js:1677bootstrap @ angular.js:1698angularInit @ angular.js:1592(anonymous function) @ angular.js:29652trigger @ angular.js:3069defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3358eventHandler @ angular.js:3346
```

Even if I uninstall angular-animate again, the error remains. I can't find any solutions to this issue on the net.

Could this be a karma issue or bower related?

Thanks for any help!

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Solution: when installing angular-animate with 'bower install angular-animate' choose the right angular-version when bower asks you for it(for ng-boilerplate v0.3.1 it is angularjs v1.2.29).

And the error vanishes...